# Preferred method for making negative statements

Tags: sentence-construction, writing

> Britain's economic fortunes **are inseparable** from the world situation.
>
> Britain's economic fortunes **are not separable** from the world situation.

Which style is preferable in professional writing? Using a negative auxiliary verb followed by a positive adjective or using a positive auxiliary verb followed by a negative adjective?

Comment: Presumably the source has been talking about the connection. Personally I think both sentences are worse than "are connected to the world situation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As The Photon stated in his answer, both sentences you gave are acceptable and nearly identical in meaning.  In general, a negative adjective emphasizes the adjective itself (the fact of being inseparable), while the negated verb emphasizes the negation of the positive adjective (it's **not** separable).

However, it's not always that simple for negative adjectives.  There are many negative adjectives in English that have stronger connotations than the negated adjective itself.  For example:

- *Immature*, when applied to people in particular, is much more negative than *not mature*.  "He is immature" implies that the person being discussed is childish, unreasonable, and/or prone to foolish actions.  "He is not mature," while still implying a lack of adult responsibility, is not as negative and points more to a lack of age or experience.
- An *immoral* action violates a set of standards or morals, while an *amoral* action is one taken without considering any standard of right or wrong.  Neither of these words is accurately expressed by the phrase *not moral*.
- *Not usual*, as in "not the usual way." means outside normal circumstance or habit. *Unusual*, as in "an unusual way," also means strange or bizarre in addition to the meaning of *not usual*.

Not every adjective has this separation of meaning between positive and negative, but it's worth looking up all the meanings of any negative adjective you're unsure about.

Answer (score 1):

Either one is grammatically acceptable. Which one to use is up to the style of the writer, and what the writer is trying to emphasize in the sentence.

For example, if the previous sentence quoted some authority as saying that Britain should isolate itself financially from other countries, the second sentence would emphasize the writer's disagreement with that position.